# Communication of child processes

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child, ipc

I am trying to write a program that creates N child processes and with each one of the process to add the first element of a stack. I tried mmap, but it only works for one child per time, is pipes or signals the only way to go ? Thank you in advance!
Here is some code

N number of processes
heap has N*10 elements

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if(fork() == 0){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            //here i want each child process, add the PopMin element 
            //(the root of a heap), to the sum variable,but when creating a child,
            //it creates a copy of the original heap, how can i make
            // this heap shared ??
            sum += PopMin(heap);
        }
        exit(0);   
    }
}
for (j=0; j<N; j++){
    wait(0);
}
```

Comment: You could used pipes, signals, sockets, shared memory, [and all sorts of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Which you choose is ultimately up to you. That said, avoid asking which is "best", as it would be trolling opinion, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Have you considered multithreading? `pthread_create`

Comment: I have to do it with processes...

Comment: You should add some code.  Sentences like _only works for one child_ require some explanation, as we don't know what you intend to do with the memory mapped.  Show a simple, (working or nonworkin) but complete program, that we can test without first modifying it to make it runnable.